# Different Ways to Declare a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm having trouble understanding the correct ways to declare a linked list. I read online that all of the following syntaxes are correct:

```
LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Why is this the case? Are there any differences between them, or will they all create the same list?

Comment: both are wrong: `new LinkedList<int>()` should not compile with Java - it would be `new LinkedList<Integer>()`  or even  `new LinkedList<>()` (diamond notation, type not needed to be repeated);  and a third alternative, assuming the 2 are corrected: `var list3 = LinkedList<Integer>();` (this needs the type)

Comment: @user16320675 While all what you said is true I suspect that main point of question was confusion between `List` vs `LinkedList`, so I edited the incorrect `<int>` part. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: The latter (interface) is to prefer! ...but sometimes if you need some implementation specific "things", you better go with first (concrete class..instead of casting it every time). A rule of thumb: (declare your variable) as general as you can and as specific as needed.